# How do I attach cloth apron well enough to character so that I can animate without the apron going through the character?

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

Very new to Blender. I have been successful in creating my cloth apron and having it lay nicely on my rigged character mesh/model during the cloth simulation. However, when I begin animating and posing my character, the cloth does not follow the character and the body of the character goes through the cloth mesh. Any help would be appreciated! Attached is the link with pictures to my settings and modifiers. [Blender Pics and Blend File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YD8EnVSXLfPt7-YQ8wo0kXpTF-sFMYP8?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are several tutorial videos on animating characters with cloth.  you should search in places like YouTube (search "blender animate character with cloth"), or here in blender exchange "[cloth-simulation] [animation]".   You'll need to have a frame 1 pose with your cloth hanging as you desire and progress towards a first pose, and then run the cloth simulation to that point.  Be prepared for playing with many parameters; it isn't very simple.

Comment: Two things: 1) Please edit your question, then upload and add the images directly to your question so readers get a quick overview and the images don't get lost. 2) Cloth simulation + animation is very challenging because of the collision detection and clipping issues. The cloth probably doesn't follow your character because of the wrong order of the modifiers on the stack. Modifiers work from the top down. The armature modifier must be above the cloth modifier because it moves the character. Check the modifiers tab.

Comment: @Blunder Thank you for your response! The images are too large atm. I can upload them to the post sometime tomorrow. I made this post right before work haha.

Comment: @james_t thanks for the suggestion! Surprisingly there are only a few tutorials out there atm. I have looked at most of them but have not achieved success. I will try searching more in depth on this site tomorrow. I am starting to realize that this is definitely a difficult task!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)